# Failed review audit because I didn't do anything with a "very poor quality" answer--but my comment was rejected

Tags: discussion

While reviewing, I attempted to make a comment on this answer

[image]

in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993570/differnce-between-hadoop-1-and-hadoop-2), but it was rejected with "Cannot add comments to this post. It may be locked, deleted, or frozen."

I therefore decided to hit the "looks okay" button, instead of the "skip" button, at which point I was flagged with a "failed audit".

I noticed afterwards that I should have just upvoted the existing "link only answer" comment, but I don't think this should result in a rejection.

Comment: If a post was removed, that's a decent hint you've came to an audit or you're reviewing too late. For the first you would DV / take action, for the second you would Skip, not use "looks okay". Audits are chosen by algorithm and are supposed to show you posts with serious problems that demanded community attention or were removed by a moderator.

Comment: Well, okay, it *should* have flagged me for a bad audit, since I did press the "looks okay" button. But the fact that I did indeed attempt to comment on it, but failed the audit "because I didn't do anything with a very poor quality question"...it basically tricked me. I know for next time, anyway.

Comment: Darn. Failed another audit  ;)

Answer (score 4):

<s>Not sure why you tagged your question with bug. There is no bug here. You can't comment on deleted answers.</s>

That is a [link only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), so the correct answer was to recommend deletion ***not*** looks ok.

> I noticed afterwards that I should have just upvoted the existing
>   "link only answer" comment

You don't need to upvote those comments. When you click on **recommend deletion** and choose a reason other than *no comment* , it will automatically leave a comment for you, or upvote the comment if it already exists from someone else.

Comment: Recommending deletion and claiming that it looks OK are not answers. Watch out for verbs on questions like these.

Comment: I changed the bug tag to discussion. The answer was presented as an *existing* answer during a review. I understand now it was actually already deleted.

Comment: @aliteralmind well, reviews audits are presented as existing answers. That's by design.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this answer's review history, it's possible that the post was automatically deleted while I was looking at it. In that case, it was just a coincidence. (Although I don't understand how it would also be an "audit".)

[image]

Either way, I get that I shouldn't have hit "looks okay."